# TCP can't connect to localserver

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I have a problem with TCP in visual basic as I'm getting the following error:

> 'Send' is not a member of
>   'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient'.   C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Launcher\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Elite
>   Team Launcher.vb  56  21  WindowsApplication1

this is the code:

```
Dim client As New TcpClient
client.Connect("192.168.1.103", 7775)
Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
client.Send(sendbytes, 0, sendbytes.Length)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Send`. You need to use `Write` instead on the `Stream` returned from `GetStream`.

You can see here how to use a `TcpClient` appropriately.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Then i get Error 1 'Write' is not a member of 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient'. C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Launcher\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Elite Team Launcher.vb 56 21 WindowsApplication1

Comment: @Nathaniel : Read his answer again. _"use `Write` instead **on the STREAM returned from `GetStream`**"_